# clustre apache ignite (2.9.1-1) ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ignite

for testing, I build a clustre apache ignite (2.9.1-1) when starting first node, everything is ok, when starting second nodes, I get an error (Failed to add node to topology because it has the same hash code for partitioned affinity as one of existing nodes) since I am not an expert in apache-ignite, I wanted to clarify how I can fix this error

Comment: Please share node configuration.

Comment: HI first node config:

Comment: Hi node-config [link](https://disk.yandex.ru/d/P5mdkAd5WnfdwA) so it is very large and gets more limt by the number of characters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify different `consistentId` for every node in the cluster.

In this case, it is possible that you are starting both nodes with `myIgniteNode01`.

Comment: HI I changed the name to second mode on myIgniteNode2 but the error persists, I attach the log maybe it will be more clear what I'm doing wrong [links log] (https://disk.yandex.ru/d/Hez-F151P4r8Eg)

Comment: I can see only one log and it still says `myIgniteNode01`.